# Spring WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext) returns null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have set up a SpringDispatcherServlet but when I call

```
  WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(MoJV.servletContext)
```

it returns null,

what am I missing?

Comment: If you said at what moment you do the call, and if the application works correctly, maybe somebody could have an idea ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I do it from a controller, so I believe everything should be ready at that time..

Comment: What is MoJV.servletContext? Does it return the ServletContext? If you need the Application context just @autowire it: `@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;`

Comment: Yes, autowiring worked. That method call should be removed! Just spent 2 hours on this :(

Comment: The `WebApplicationContextUtils` return the root application context, the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` if you don't have that it returns `null`. Intead use the `RequestContextUtils` to get the application context for the current `DispatcherServlet`. This is also explained in the javadoc of the respective classes.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get why the applicationContext is based on the request. There should only be one such object. How do I use ContextLoaderListener to initiate teh WebApplicatoinContextUtils one. My web.xml looks like this: http://pastebin.com/hrDRFCqm

Comment: Ok, figured it out: <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/config/EmptyConfig.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

However, do I really need to add an empty config for this, can I not  hook up the dispatcher to provide one? The DispatcherServlet(WebApplication... ) exists ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

Comment: A bit of an explanation would be nice here. Try to avoid posting just code. Thanks!

Comment: Not really. Some people might not be familiar with `@Autowired`.

Comment: This is not a very descriptive answer to the problem, especially since it doesn't solve the issue where the getWebApplicationContext was returning null, but tries to go through a different mechanism that doesn't work in all situations.